# LUIS Dispatch refresh Changes the production slot

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have a Microsoft LUIS Dispatch model. Whenever, I try to use **dispatch refresh all the child models gets published into the Production Slot automatically**. I want to first publish the dispatch into staging for test purpose and then only to Production. How to achieve this? Am I missing any key in the .dispatch file?

```
{
  "authoringRegion": "westus",
  "hierarchical": true,
  "useAllTrainingData": false,
  "dontReviseUtterance": false,
  "copyLuisData": true,
  "normalizeDiacritics": true,
  "appId": "DispatchAppId",
  "authoringKey": "AuthKey",
  "version": "v3",
  "region": "westus",
  "type": "dispatch",
  "name": "DispatchModel"
  "services": [
    {
      "intentName": "l_Model1",
      "appId": "MyAppid-1",
      "authoringKey": "AuthKey",
      "version": "v3",
      "region": "westus",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "Model1",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "intentName": "l_Model2",
      "appId": "MyAppid-2",
      "authoringKey": "AuthKey",
      "version": "v3",
      "region": "westus",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "Model2",
      "id": "1"
    }
  ],
  "serviceIds": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
}
```

Thanks,
pdeepa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has something to do with using the `--publishToStaging` option as stated in the Dispatch Command Line tool repo in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#creating-your-dispatch-model) section.

Here's an example:

```
dispatch create [options]
dispatch create --publishToStaging true --useAllTrainingData true
dispatch create --bot c:\src\bot\testbot.bot --secret <your_bot_file_secret>
dispatch create --dontImport true --useAllTrainingData true
```

There's also a workaround, which is to use the direct version publishing feature as stated in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/1413#issuecomment-591142103) issue:

> 1. Publish the updated child model using direct version publishing.
>    This can be done only via calling REST API for now (not yet
>    available in the LUIS UI) by setting the "directVersionPublish"flag
>    in publish request body to true. API reference here.
> 2. Make sure that the dispatch parent is linked to the same versionId
>    as the one used in direct version publishing.
> 3. After republishing the dispatch parent, you are expected to see the
>    results of the child application version that was published with
>    direct version publishing. An important note is that this will
>    change all the published slots of the dispatch parent to point to
>    the directly published version of the child.
> 4. Optionally, if you want to test changes in the dispatch parent model
>    itself without publishing it to the PRODUCTION slot, you can
>    actually use direct version publish the dispatch parent, and query
>    it with the [endpoint V3 APIs](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-endpoint-api-v3-0-preview/operations/5cb0a9459a1fe8fa44c28dd8).